# Private directory mounted without passphrase?

Tags: ecryptfs

After setting up a private directory in ~/Private, I noticed that ecryptfs-mount-private is able to mount the directory without supplying a passphrase.

Is there a way to disable this behaviour, to force ecryptfs to ask for a passphrase (and entirely disable automounting using a key in the keyring)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [EncryptedPrivateDirectory](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedPrivateDirectory) wiki:

> We can stop ecryptfs from unlocking the Private folder on startup, by removing the empty file `auto-mount` which is located in `~/.ecryptfs/`, where you also can remove the  `auto-umount` file, if you would like ecryptsfs to stop unmounting the private folder upon shutdown and logout.

**UPDATE:** To fix the issue of `~/Private` being mountable without using a password, follow the instructions in this [Ubuntu Forums post](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1277212.html):

> OK Folks, here is the true fix.
>
> I was reading an article on ecryptfs (http://ecryptfs.sourceforge.net/ecryptfs-pam-doc.txt) and found that PAM is involved and thus started looking in /etc/pam.d/ and found 2 files that need to be modified:
>
> `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`
>    `/etc/pam.d/common-session`
>
> Do the following as root, but make a backup copy first in a directory OUT OF this directory like `~/` or it will possibly run the backup which is unmodified.
>
> In `/etc/pam.d/common-session` look for a line that says:
>
> `auth  optional    pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap`
>   and comment it out like:
>   `#auth optional    pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap`
>
> In `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` look for a line that says:
>
> `session   optional    pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap`
>   and comment it out like
>   `#session   optional    pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap`
>
> Both files must be modified. The common-session file is what cause the actually mounting and the common-auth unwraps the passphrase.
>
> If just common-session is commented out (as I tried first), all one has to do is type ecrypt-mount-private and it will mount without the login passphrase. This is NOT GOOD. So the common-auth must be modified to prevent the loading of the unwrapped passphrase into the kernel.
>
> The caveat to this is that THIS AFFECTS ALL USERS. I have just discovered the above by rooting around myself and it satisfies my needs. However, it will make it more difficult on a multiuser system for novices as the Private will not be automatically mounted. There may be a way to prevent this on a user-level (not system level) but I don't know how to do that.
>
> Hope this helps someone in the future.
>
> Yours,
>   Narnie

You will need to restart your computer after you modify those files.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't answer the question as I was not talking about having the Directory mounted at startup - I was talking about the fact that ecryptfs-mount-private doesn't ask for the password, but instead grabs the password from a keyfile from a keychain. and I don't know where that keyfile is stored, nor how to disable it. right now, it makes the whole encrypting process rather useless, as you only need to doubleclick "Access-your-Private-Data" in `~/Private` to have the directory mounted and read/writable. but I want ecryptfs to ask for the password, instead of using a keyfile.

Comment: @nebukadnezzar See my updated answer.

Comment: I've just rebooted with said changes, and it works like a charme. thanks! :D

Answer (score 2):

The absolutely trivial-but-effective way to solve the question as asked is to simple remove `~/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase` (or rename it).

This will totally prevent pam_ecryptfs from loading any keys into the keyring.

Comment: The deletion causes the error message ERROR: Encrypted private directory is not setup properly